# apache drill execute udf 2 times and the answer is not I want

Tags: java, apache-drill

I have written a class to decode the customer id of our company with a secret key. The decryption algorithm is DES.

I then re-factored the below code and changed the algorithm from DES to AES , but when I run a select function , the decryption runs twice. First with the right result and then the second result is wrong. (So the final result is wrong)

I list my code here ：

```
package org.apache.drill.exec.fn.impl;

import com.google.common.base.Charsets;
import io.netty.buffer.DrillBuf;
import org.apache.commons.codec.DecoderException;
import org.apache.commons.codec.net.BCodec;
import org.apache.drill.exec.expr.DrillSimpleFunc;
import org.apache.drill.exec.expr.annotations.FunctionTemplate;
import org.apache.drill.exec.expr.annotations.Output;
import org.apache.drill.exec.expr.annotations.Param;
import org.apache.drill.exec.expr.annotations.Workspace;
import org.apache.drill.exec.expr.holders.VarCharHolder;

import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.DESKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import javax.inject.Inject;

@functiontemplate(
name = "decode_cid",
scope = FunctionTemplate.FunctionScope.SIMPLE,
nulls = FunctionTemplate.NullHandling.NULL_IF_NULL
)

public class DecodeCidFunction implements DrillSimpleFunc {

@Param
VarCharHolder raw_input;
// @Param
// VarCharHolder raw_key;

@Output
VarCharHolder out;

@Inject
DrillBuf buffer;
// @workspace
// KeyGenerator keygenerator;

@Workspace
SecretKey myDesKey;

@Workspace
Cipher desCipher;

@Workspace
BCodec bCodec;

@Override
public void setup() {
    try {
        String key = "this is a secret";
        javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory factory = javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");
        myDesKey = factory.generateSecret(new javax.crypto.spec.DESKeySpec(key.getBytes())) ;
        System.out.println("myDesKey = "+myDesKey.toString());
        // Create the cipher
        desCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");

        // Initialize the cipher for encryption
        desCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, myDesKey);

        bCodec =  new BCodec("UTF-8");

    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("may i come here");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void eval() {
    String input = org.apache.drill.exec.expr.fn.impl.StringFunctionHelpers.toStringFromUTF8(raw_input.start, raw_input.end, raw_input.buffer);
    String output = "";
    System.out.println("input = " + input);
    if (input.startsWith("=?"))
    {
        try{
            output = bCodec.decode(input);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("find an error :" +e.toString());
            output  = "";
        }
    }else{
        byte[] bts = new byte[input.length() / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < bts.length; i++) {
            bts[i] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(input.substring(2*i, 2*i+2), 16);
        }
        System.out.println("bts = " +bts.toString());
        try{
            byte[] decodedString = desCipher.doFinal(bts) ;
            output = new String(decodedString, "utf-8");
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("i come here " + e.toString());
            output="";
        }
    }
    System.out.println("output = " + output);
    out.buffer = buffer;
    out.start = 0;
    out.end = output.getBytes().length;
    buffer.setBytes(0, output.getBytes());
}
}
```

The output:

And my select query is below :+1:

```
0: jdbc:drill:zk=local> select decode_cid('A849333D2713FAFEA10780AD02139B29') from (values(1));
myDesKey = com.sun.crypto.provider.DESKey@183d7
input = A849333D2713FAFEA10780AD02139B29
bts = [B@22f4128e
output = 20138690
myDesKey = com.sun.crypto.provider.DESKey@18301
input = A849333D2713FAFEA10780AD02139B29
bts = [B@7a69714
    I come here javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
output =
+---------+
| EXPR$0 |
+---------+
| |
+---------+
1 row selected (3.075 seconds)
```

You can see the first output is right , however the second is null ,null is not I want. I want to know why it runs two twice ?

Comment: I tried my best to fix the grammar and explain how you tried to re-factor the code to convert from DES decryption to AES decryption.

Comment: Thank you very much !  I really wonder why it execute 2 times  and  after the first execution the key has changed , and the rersult of the first execution is what I want

Answer (score 1):

Since 1.11 Apache Drill includes implementation of some crypto functions including AES [1]. Link to source code - https://github.com/apache/drill/blob/master/exec/java-exec/src/main/java/org/apache/drill/exec/expr/fn/impl/CryptoFunctions.java#L272-L384

[1] https://drill.apache.org/blog/2017/07/31/drill-1.11-released/

Comment: What you said is all right , Although drill has implement some algorithm , des description is not implemented, and I want to implement a custom algorithm is base on the business of our company , I just wonder why It execute 2 times and I found the key changed after the first execution , what happened to the keys  , I just want know why it execute 2 times , can it only execute exactly one time ?

Comment: I have tried your code and from the output I see that the error was twice (not like in your example, where it was only once): `myDesKey = com.sun.crypto.provider.DESKey@18cb9
input = A849333D2713FAFEA10780AD02139B29
bts = [B@3422de25
i come here javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
output = 
myDesKey = com.sun.crypto.provider.DESKey@18cb9
input = A849333D2713FAFEA10780AD02139B29
bts = [B@7222c376
i come here javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
output = `

Comment: The reason you see different results, is because if you make any changes in your function code, you need to rebuild the project. Since Drill uses udf source code which is added to target classes location during the build.

Comment: The thing that you see that function was executed twice it's because you have constant in you query. Calcite tries to optimize the query and uses function code but that results will be discarded since Drill will use source code anyway. So basically to solve your problem you just need to re-build the project and function will start to return correct results.

Comment: Actually I rebuild my project  after modification , but it doesn't work , I just run :  mvn clean  and then  mvn package , but the result is always the same

Comment: you tried my example, that's great, the key of the example is a secret of our company,so I can't put it into the example ,I'm so sorry

Comment: I followed the instruction of this site ,https://community.mapr.com/community/exchange/blog/2017/04/05/apache-drill-how-to-create-a-new-function  , and I have write a custom mask function , it works good ,but I write a des decription function , it doesn't work , I'm so sad, the pom file is allmost the same

Comment: The code that you have listed, seems to be fine. If double execution of function bothers you, you may try to use your query without constants: `select decrypt(version) from sys.version`. Maybe it's your des decription function logic is incorrect? You may you can use `aes_decrypt` function code that is present in Drill, change it step by step and find out what is wrong. Just don't forget to do `mvn clean install` after each code change.

Comment: You may also use unit tests to check (ex: https://github.com/apache/drill/blob/master/exec/java-exec/src/test/java/org/apache/drill/exec/fn/impl/TestContextFunctions.java)

Comment: That's  great， I  just  wonder  how to debug my program , thank you very much

Comment: The easy option is to write unit test with constant expression thus you'll be able to put debug breakpoint in your code. Changes in code won't affect the final output (as I have mentioned earlier, you'll need to do mvn clean install first) but you'll be able to see what is going on. Without constant expression, you'll need to deal with generated classes debugging in Drill.